# How to generate DOT language output on Python

Tags: python, windows, pygraphviz

I am trying to gather data from twitter and visualize it through Graphviz. I have already installed Graphviz and currently I am trying to generate a DOT language output through Python, I ran into the problem of not being able to get any response from my code. I would like to know if my code has generated a DOT file or not and if yes, where is my DOT file? Below is my code.

```
OUT ="Paul_search_results.dot"
try:
    nx.drawing.write_dot(g, OUT)
except ImportError, e:
    dot = ['"%s" -> "&s" [tweet_id=%s]'% (n1, n2, g[n1][n2]['tweet_id'])\
           for n1, n2 in g.edges()]
    f = open(OUT, 'w')
    f.write('strict digraph {\n%s\n}' % (';\n'.join(dot),))
    f.close()
```

I am using windows and I know I can't `easy_install pygraphviz`, but the code above should do the same thing. According to the book, I should have DOT language output on hand with the code above. But I didn't get any response from my code.

I already have gathered the information from twitter and the nodes and edges ready.

```
>>> g.number_of_nodes()
235
>>> g.number_of_edges()
202
```

Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: Could you post a part of `dot`'s contents?

Comment: You can download [graphviz for windows](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php), then the python bindings should install correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is stored in `Paul_search_results.dot`.  If you can't find that find, then change the name to include the full path so you can put it where you want it.

The rest of the code looks correct but it is hard to tell without seeing the data.  You set `f=sys.stdout` in order to see the output being generated.

FYI, there is an on-line version of Graphviz available at http://interactive.blockdiag.com

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I changed the name and it worked... I don't know why the initial name I can't find it... But brilliant idea of changing the name. Thanks, :)

Answer (score 1):

If `nx.drawing.write_dot()` or `f.write()` wrote any output to `Paul_search_results.dot`, that file will be located in your "Current working directory". I haven't got a clue what Windows will set your current working directory to if you just double-click the file in `Explorer.exe` -- it would be well worth your time to start a `cmd.exe` command prompt, perform the `cd` yourself to whichever directory you want to contain your output, run the command by hand, and then look over the console output to see if there are any error messages.